# how to change date format 21 dec '15 to 21-12-2015 in php

Tags: php

I want to change date format like

```
$date ="21 dec '15";
```

to

```
$date ="21-12-2015";
```

How can it is possible in php.

Comment: How do you get the `$date` variable ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $result['month']);

echo $date->format('F');
```

F `stands for "month name",`

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$date = "21 dec '2015"; #your date 
$replaced_date = str_replace("'","",$date);
$new = date_create($replaced_date);
$new_date = date_format($new, "d-m-Y"); # restructer the date
echo $new_date ;
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4axz-ry76)

Comment: My date is $date ="21 dec '15"; here single quote before year

Comment: you are right. but any single function available for it ? i don't want use str_replace function because date format i get different different

Comment: You can simplify this to 2 or 3 lines. I add all steps to take idea about what is did

Comment: @RonakPatel so that make valid date form your excel file

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = new DateTime(str_replace("'", '20', "21 dec '15"));

var_dump($date->format('d-m-Y'));
```